# Using first bit as a flag in an unsigned int

Tags: c++, c++11, bit

I am trying to use the first bit of an unsigned int as a flag if the client as server should re-key for their encryption keys. I would like to use the rest of the unsigned int as the length for the remaining data that is being sent.

Currently I am trying this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
unsigned int payloadLength;
read(sock, &payloadLength, sizeof(payloadLength));
short bit = (payloadLength >> 0) & 1U; // get first bit

payloadLength &= 1UL << 0; // set first bit to 0
payloadLength = ntohl(payloadLength);

if (bit == 1) 
   //rekey
else
  //read more data
```

The rekey flag seems to be set right, but when trying to get the length it always ends up as the wrong number.

Edit: I should have clarified I meant most significant bit, not first bit

Comment: It's fairly unusual to see something bitshifted by zero positions, since that operation has no effect (it's like adding zero or multiplying by one). Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do in those lines?

Comment: `(payloadLength >> 0)` is no-op. Your code can't do what you think it is doing.

Comment: _The wrong number_: what sort?  double what you expect?  rounded down to even?  Something unrelated to your expected number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at this code:

```
short bit = (payloadLength >> 0) & 1U; // get first bit
payloadLength &= 1UL << 0; // set first bit to 0
payloadLength = ntohl(payloadLength);
```

Although it's perfectly legal for you to order these statements this way, there's a risk that this won't work the way you want it to. Specifically, you probably want to decode the payload to use the host byte ordering *before* you start poking and prodding the bytes. Otherwise, if you send data from one system to another, there's a risk that you'll be reading the wrong bits back. But that's not too hard to fix - just move the last statement, which decodes `payloadLength`, to the top, like this:

```
/* CAUTION: This still has errors! */
payloadLength = ntohl(payloadLength);
short bit = (payloadLength >> 0) & 1U; // get first bit
payloadLength &= 1UL << 0; // set first bit to 0
```

Next, there's a question about which bit you are trying to read. It looks like you are trying to read the least-significant bit of the number. If that's the case, you don't need to include any bitshifts, as bitshifting by zero positions doesn't have any effect. Let's remove those, giving this:

```
/* CAUTION: This still has errors! */
payloadLength = ntohl(payloadLength);
short bit = payloadLength & 1U; // get first bit
payloadLength &= 1UL; // set first bit to 0
```

Your code to extract the final bit of the number is correct. It'll mask out everything except the lowest bit, then store the value in the variable `bit`. (Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're storing this as a `short`? If you're looking for a boolean "do I need to reencode this?," you might want to just go with `bool` and write something like

```
bool reencode = (payloadLength & 1U) != 0;
```

That's up to you to decide, though.)

However, your code to *clear* the last bit is incorrect. Right now, when you write

```
payloadLength &= 1UL; // set first bit to 0
```

you are actually doing the opposite of what you intended - you're clearing every bit *except* the first. That's because if you AND `payloadLength` with a value, you're zeroing every bit in `payloadLength` except for the bits that are equal to 1 in `1UL`. However, `1UL` only has a 1 bit in the last position. You probably meant to write something like

```
payloadLength &= ~1UL; // set first bit to 0
```

where the ~ operator flips the bits of your mask. Overall, this would give you the following:

```
payloadLength = ntohl(payloadLength);
short bit = payloadLength & 1U; // get first bit
payloadLength &= ~1UL; // set first bit to 0
```

I have one last question, though. By repurposing the lowest bit of the number this way, you are requiring that your payload length always be an even number, since you're harnessing the 1's bit of the payload length to encode whether to rekey. If you're okay with that, great! You don't need to do anything.

On the other hand, if that's an issue, you have a couple of options, which I'll leave to you to select from:

1. Instead of using the least-significant bit, use the *most*-significant bit. This will cause problems if you try to send payloads of size 2<sup>31</sup> or higher, though.
2. Use the least-significant bit, but have the upper 31 bits of the number represent the actual payload length. To extract the payload length, just shift everything over one position. This has the drawback of not supporting payloads of size 2<sup>31</sup> or greater, though.
3. Don't use the bits at all to encode this! Instead, send a payload length, then have the payload start with a header that tells you whether to rekey, etc. This uses more bytes per payload, but also gives you more flexibility in the future (what if you need to send other flags as well?)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should have clarified, I did mean to get the most significant bit. In my mind the first was the first when reading right to left, I see where I made an error.  
Thank you, your answer really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

`payloadLength &= 1UL << 0;` will zero all bits other than the first one.
`payloadLength &= ~1UL;` will zero the first bit.